# Help finding the arc length?

Tags: circles

What is the arc length if $Θ = 6\pi/5$(sorry, dont know how to format that)   and the radius is $2$ cm?

- length of arc= $n/360= 2\pi(r)$
  is it $2/360=2\pi(r)
  2\pi(180)$?

Comment: For $\pi$ , just put $ tags around \pi . For a fraction, you can do like you did, or use $ with \frac {}{} , where first you put numerator then denominator

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. For some basic information about writing maths at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latexhelp/notation).

Answer (score 0):

The arc length formula is $L=r\theta$, so the length is $\frac {12\pi}5$ cm.